# NSPredicate Subqueries

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_SyncEntries WHERE syncDataType == 1 AND 
syncLastSuccessOnDt == (SELECT max(syncLastSuccessOnDt) FROM tbl_SyncEntries 
WHERE syncDataType==1)
```

How to formulate a NSPredicate for the above SQL statement?

I would like to retrieve the record, where the `syncDataType == 1` and the recent date on which syncDataType 1 was synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Core Data, you would

- fetch objects where `syncDataType == 1`,
- sorted descending by `syncLastSuccessOnDt`, and
- limit the result set to 1.

so what you need is the `NSFetchRequest`. (The `NSPredicate` is only one parameter of the
fetch request.)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = your managed object context
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SyncEntry"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"syncDataType = %d", 1];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"syncLastSuccessOnDt" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

[request setFetchLimit:1];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    // Error
} else if ([results count] == 0) {
    // Nothing found
} else {
    NSManagedObject *obj = results[0];
    NSDate *lastSync = [obj valueForKey:@"syncLastSuccessOnDt"];
}
```

If you have created a managed object subclass `SyncEntry` for your entity, the last part can
be written as

```
SyncEntry *obj = results[0];
NSDate *lastSync = obj.syncLastSuccessOnDt;
```

Comment: Thanks for [request setFetchLimit:1];